# Anonymous function returning null when dumping

Tags: php

**The Overview**

I've been experimenting some features which I've learn't using `PHP`, last night I was working on anonymous functions and for some strange reason when I `var_dump`ed the function it kept returning `null`.

**The Code**

Below is the code I've written.

The `findOrFail` function,

```
public static function findOrFail($iD, $successCallback = null, $failCallback = null)
{
    $db = new Database();

    $db->select("users")->fields(["*"])->where(["id" => $iD])->execute("select");

    if ($db->rowCount() == 1) {
        if (is_callable($successCallback)) {
            return $successCallback();
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if (is_callable($failCallback)) {
            return $failCallback($iD);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In **test.php**,

```
require_once "config.php";

var_dump(User::findOrFail(1, function () {
    echo "Found.";
}, function ($iD) {
    echo "Failed.";
}));
```

**The Output**

The ID 1 exsits so I expect the see when dumping string and the contents to be "Found." however I see this:

`Found.NULL`

**What I have tried?**

- I looked at another question related to this issue and it said
  that it was because of a buggy `PHP` version (5.3?). So I checked my
  `PHP` version and it is **5.5.8**.
- I thought maybe because the default parameters (`$successCallback` and `$failCallback`) are set to equal `null` that that may be causing the error to occur. However some quick changes to the code (to remove the `null`) showed that it didn't fix anything.

So my question is, **Why is it showing null?** If anyone could shed some light on this issue it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your anonymous functions don't return anything, they just call `echo` to print something. Use:

```
return "Found";
```

and

```
return "Failed";
```

Comment: After seeing your reply my question seems immediately pointless. I'm not sure if I should delete it however in the mean time I'll accept your answer *in 7 minutes*. Thanks a lot.